# How to convert FAT32 disk to NTFS without losing data

Tags: ntfs, fat32

Please suggest How to convert FAT32 disk to NTFS without losing data

Answer (score 14):

CONVERT C: /FS:NTFS

It's not optimal because the cluster size is not ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Microsoft KB article on this - [How to convert a FAT16 volume or a FAT32 volume to an NTFS file system in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881).